# 400 bad request, Spring MVC REST Controller, Android RX + Retrofit

Tags: android, spring-mvc, rx-java, retrofit2

On server side I have following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/save", produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServerResponse setUserData(@RequestBody User user) {
    return new ServerResponse("User: " + user.getId());
}
```

When I try to send json data from Android I get 400 error from Retrofit:

```
@POST("api/save")
Observable<ServerResponse> saveData(@Body User user);
```

D/OkHttp: --> POST http://XXX.XX.X.X:8080/mysite/api/save http/1.1

D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 102
D/OkHttp: {"email":"email@gmail.com","firstName":"first name","id":1,"lastName":"last name","password":"password"}

D/OkHttp: --> END POST (102-byte body)

D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://XXX.XX.X.X:8080/mysite/api/save (124ms))

The message from Apache Tomcat is:
HTTP Status 400 - the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I would really appreciate if someone can help to me. Regards!

Comment: You should probably include the stack trace for either the server or the client....

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What do you mean?

Comment: Full description of the errors that you see in your debugging console

Comment: @MaximOstrovidov  It's not exactly an error, just does not pass the request.
Added to question

Comment: The problem has been in JSON data what i sending. Incorrect value type. Instead int i  was using boolean :D